# Problemas ao importar dados com o Microsoft Excel Input

Tags: pentaho

Estou importando várias planilhas pra um banco de dados, mas algumas delas estão apresentando problemas no input. Já tentei inclusive transformar o formato e usar o CSV File Input, mas o problema continua o mesmo.

Os dados no Excel estão assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tento importar, algumas colunas "trocam de lugar" e os dados de uma, vão para outra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso, por exemplo, os dados da coluna `camada_nome` foram parar na coluna `profund_inf`
Alguém sabe porque isso ocorre? Tem solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você esta utilizando o Step Table Output para efetuar os insert, vale lembrar que, caso você não especifique onde cada coluna deve ser inserida, o Pentaho irá se comportar assumindo que a tabela recebida esta na mesma ordem da tabela do Banco, por essa razão os dados da terceira coluna de entrada (camada_nome) fora inseridos na terceira coluna da tabela (profund_inf).

Solução 1(a mais fácil) - Igualar o layout da tabela de input, ao layout da tabela do banco. Isso pode ser feito através do step 'Select Values'. Basta espelhar os layouts, caso a tabela de input não possua todas as colunas da tabela do banco, você pode criar as colunas com valores vazios com o step 'Add constants'.

Solução 2(não tão dificil) - No step Table output, na aba 'Database fields' você pode especificar quais dados irão ser inseridos em quais campos da tabela do banco(como um de-para). É uma boa prática fazer com que os nomes de ambas tabelas sejam identicos para não haver maiores problemas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é que eu estava deletando algumas colunas dentro do step Microsoft Excel Input e isso faz com que o kettle mova as colunas, gerando o erro das colunas trocadas. Agora tá funcionando certinho, muito obrigada!

Comment: Correto, as colunas do Microsoft Excel input tem quer ser as mesmas do layout do arquivo, caso necessite retirar colunas, ou reordena-las, utilize o step Select Values logo após. Lembrando também que adicionar colunas extras á direita do layout não influencia, o problema esta em adicionar colunas á esquerda do layout, o que causa uma nova organização dos dados, e consequentemente o erro que estava encontrando acontece.